# How to create thumbnail image from high memory image url in php?

Tags: php, image

Hi friends i want create thumbnail from image url in php, am finding one code to generate thumb image from url ,it's working for low memory size image url, NOT WORKING FOR High Memory size image url, please give some solution for this problem.

```
<?php

// function created by www.thewebhelp.com

if(!function_exists("create_square_image")){
    function create_square_image($original_file, $destination_file=thumb, $square_size = 96){

        if(isset($destination_file) and $destination_file!=NULL){
            if(!is_writable($destination_file)){
                echo '<p style="color:#FF0000">Oops, the destination path is not writable. Make that file or its parent folder wirtable.</p>'; 
            }
        }

        // get width and height of original image
        $imagedata = getimagesize($original_file);
        $original_width = $imagedata[0];    
        $original_height = $imagedata[1];

        if($original_width > $original_height){
            $new_height = $square_size;
            $new_width = $new_height*($original_width/$original_height);
        }
        if($original_height > $original_width){
            $new_width = $square_size;
            $new_height = $new_width*($original_height/$original_width);
        }
        if($original_height == $original_width){
            $new_width = $square_size;
            $new_height = $square_size;
        }

        $new_width = round($new_width);
        $new_height = round($new_height);

        // load the image
        if(substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".jpg") or substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".jpeg")){
            $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_file);
        }
        if(substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".gif")){
            $original_image = imagecreatefromgif($original_file);
        }
        if(substr_count(strtolower($original_file), ".png")){
            $original_image = imagecreatefrompng($original_file);
        }

        $smaller_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $square_image = imagecreatetruecolor($square_size, $square_size);

        imagecopyresampled($smaller_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);

        if($new_width>$new_height){
            $difference = $new_width-$new_height;
            $half_difference =  round($difference/2);
            imagecopyresampled($square_image, $smaller_image, 0-$half_difference+1, 0, 0, 0, $square_size+$difference, $square_size, $new_width, $new_height);
        }
        if($new_height>$new_width){
            $difference = $new_height-$new_width;
            $half_difference =  round($difference/2);
            imagecopyresampled($square_image, $smaller_image, 0, 0-$half_difference+1, 0, 0, $square_size, $square_size+$difference, $new_width, $new_height);
        }
        if($new_height == $new_width){
            imagecopyresampled($square_image, $smaller_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $square_size, $square_size, $new_width, $new_height);
        }


        // if no destination file was given then display a png      
        if(!$destination_file){
            imagepng($square_image,NULL,9);
        }

        // save the smaller image FILE if destination file given
        if(substr_count(strtolower($destination_file), ".jpg")){
            imagejpeg($square_image,$destination_file,100);
        }
        if(substr_count(strtolower($destination_file), ".gif")){
            imagegif($square_image,$destination_file);
        }
        if(substr_count(strtolower($destination_file), ".png")){
            imagepng($square_image,$destination_file,9);
        }

        imagedestroy($original_image);
        imagedestroy($smaller_image);
        imagedestroy($square_image);

    }
}



create_square_image("imageurl","thumbname.jpg",200);
?>
```

Comment: Could be that large images reaches the memory limit of PHP? Maybe changing this limit in php.ini could solve the problem